# How to generate networks for dynamic emotion modelling

Tags: cognitive-psychology, emotion, clinical-psychology, dynamic-systems

In Figure 1 (shown below) of "Micro-Level Affect Dynamics in Psychopathology Viewed From Complex Dynamical System Theory" by Wichers et al, they claim that the emotional/affective dynamics of networks of mentally ill individuals are more highly connected than healthy controls. These highly connected networks are more sensitive to perturbations.

[image: emotion network models]

How are these networks generated? What are the meaning behind the `N` variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The networks are a stand-in for a variety of networks coming from various publications with roughly the same shape. For example, these networks from "[Emotion-Network Density in Major Depressive Disorder](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273978149_Emotion-Network_Density_in_Major_Depressive_Disorder)" comparing the causal interaction between different states for those with Major Depressive Disorder (MDD) and Healthy Controls (CTL) in various affective situations:

[image: simple network]

As well as these networks from "[Exploring the underlying structure of mental disorders: cross-diagnostic differences and similarities from a network perspective using both a top-down and a bottom-up approach](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/274088396_Exploring_the_underlying_structure_of_mental_disorders_Cross-diagnostic_differences_and_similarities_from_a_network_perspective_using_both_a_top-down_and_a_bottom-up_approach)" doing the same comparison:

[image: advanced network]

The method for creating these networks is covered in detail in "[A Network Approach to Psychopathology: New Insights into Clinical Longitudinal Data](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236207535_A_Network_Approach_to_Psychopathology_New_Insights_into_Clinical_Longitudinal_Data)".